# Twitter API V2 reply to a tweet

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitter-api-v2

I am trying hard to find a way to reply to a tweet with Twitter API V2, but it seems there is no endpoint for doing something like that, in Twitter Developer docs i found a way to post and delete a tweet, to retweet a tweet and delete a retweet, but i am struggling with replies, can you please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: I find out how to do this. Endpoint for this action is  "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets", and parameters you have to pass are "text" and "reply" object with "in_reply_to_tweet_id" key, like this "reply: { in_reply_to_tweet_id: tweet_id }

Comment: If you found a solution, please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are having trouble in the previous answer.
Pass this following in the body of the request.

```
{
    "text": "Hello World!2",
    "reply": {
        "in_reply_to_tweet_id":"175381330075023636"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

For anyone coming later at this post, here is answer:
Endpoint for this action is "api.twitter.com/2/tweets", and parameters you have to pass are "text" and "reply" object with "in_reply_to_tweet_id" key, like this "reply: { in_reply_to_tweet_id: tweet_id }

Comment: What is the encoded URI equivalent of this? 

Ex: api.twitter.com/2/tweets?query=&reply=in_reply_to_tweet_id=tweet_id,text=text

I know this isn't right but I can't figure out the format.

Comment: @edin-osmic , can you please post the complete working solution? We are getting 403 (unsupported authentication) with bearer token. Though same token works for all other API calls.

Comment: How can I get the id of the variable response since response.id does not work?

[AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'id']

response = client.create_tweet(text=tweet_msg)

client.create_tweet(text=reply_msg, in_reply_to_tweet_id=response.id)